# Could the HTML 5 Video tag pick up an IP Multicast Stream?

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video

I've been researching methods of getting an IP Multicast over UDP to the browser, and have found little that suggests I would be able to do it without using a plug-in like Java, Flash, or Silverlight in order to open a UDP port and (somehow) render the video.

Checking out the HTML 5 `<video>` spec, there is (obviously) little in the way of specific implementation details, so as far as I can tell, there is nothing stopping a browser from parsing a  address of the form "udp://224.1.1.1:8000" and joining a multicast group on that IP/port. Is this a correct understanding? Or must the resource pointed to by the `<source>` be a file?

Comment: Not an answer, but I can definitly tell you it's not possible with the flash player as it has no way to get UDP from the network...

Answer (score 0):

When you have a browser than can play RTP streams, you can probably receive that RTP from UDP multicast. Not sure which browsers currently can.